# Redmine email sending stops after changing from smtp to async_smtp

Tags: redmine

I have setup redmine and configure email sending feature with smtp.
It takes around 15 seconds for any user action to complete if email is enabled( sending email takes time at our smtp server as it has a configured delay).

So I have tried using async_smtp as shown below.

```
production:
    delivery_method: :async_smtp
    async_smtp_settings:
      enable_starttls_auto: true
      address: "smtp.xxx.com"
      port: 25
      domain: "smtp.xx.com"
      authentication: :plain
      user_name: "yyy@xxx.com"
      password: "xxx!"
```

Redmine shows that email is sent, but I couldn't see the email. Log also doesn't show any error.

Can someone help?

Adding more detail below:
with the above settings, I get success log as shown below:

```
Sent email "Redmine test" (16ms) to: [email] 
Redirected to http://[ip]/redmine/settings?tab=notifications Completed 302 Found in
328ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms) Started GET
"/redmine/settings?tab=notifications" for [ip] at 2015-10-05 15:13:04+0530
```

note: I have replaced ip and email with  [ip] and [email]

Comment: Which version of redmine are you using? Can you paste your full `production` email settings `address`,  `port`, `domain` etc thanks.

Comment: redmine-3.1.1-0. Updating the quesion with full production settings

Comment: Thanks, can you give us the output of `ruby --version` on your server?

Comment: ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13) [i386-mingw32]

Answer (score 1):

I made it work!

I found that you need to add extra level in the config file, `email_delivery`. Its hinted at elsewhere in the file, but all the examples on redmine.org miss it out. Seems that only `async` requires it.

```
production:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :async_smtp
    async_smtp_settings:
        address: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's look like it's the same problem I had, your `smtp server` can't reroute your request. I had to let my configuration to `smtp` instead of `async_smtp` as our smtp server can't handle it.

Is it your own `smtp server` or a hotmail, gmail, etc?

BTW can you try to add this `config.action_mailer.logger = nil` to your `config/environments/production.rb` configuration file, and give us the output of `log/production.log`

EDIT: Look like redmine have problem handling certain SSL certificate.

Comment: I have done that.. that is how i got the log which I posted in the question already. Log simple doesn't show any error. It says mail sent successfully.. Do you need more logs?

Comment: I'm runing into the same problem. This is due SSL certificate, look like redmine have problem handle that :(

Comment: strange that redmine team is not giving solution to it. almost all the forms talks about changing the key from smtp_settings: to async_smtp_settings:... problem after that is not discussed anywhere.. it works for few people... there is some other hidden issue

Comment: I think `async_smtp_settings` is suitable for services like gmail or stuff like that. I'm quite sure your don't use gmail in your project, am I right?

Comment: we have our own smtp server. But why should it matter? when it works with smtp_settings, it should also work with async_smtp_settings for the same server right? making the mail sending process async is not at redmine side?

Comment: I also have mine own server, I think with `async_smtp` it try to verify the SSL certificate. Why not with `smtp` that is the question....

Comment: enable_starttls_auto: true is sufficent to deal with SSL right?

Comment: Sure but it look like if the SSL certificate is self signed it won't work. BTW it could also come from the `domain` are you sure for yours ?

Comment: Cannot get `async` to work for love or money. Tried different smtp server, tried with and without `starttls`, added `domain` setting.. nothing...